# How to make default export compatible with CommonJS

Tags: typescript, wrapper, commonjs

I am currently in the process of writing a wrapper for an API in TypeScript but am currently experiencing an issue when trying to use said wrapper in CommonJS after its built.

I have a class located in `BattleMetrics.ts`;

```
export default class BattleMetrics {
    private axios: any;
    constructor(token: string) {
      ....
    }
}
```

That class is then imported into the main file, and exported as default as well;

```
import BattleMetrics from './src/BattleMetrics';

export default BattleMetrics;
```

However, once built if I make for instance a `test.js` file and write something along the lines of

```
const BattleMetrics = require('../../dist/index.js')

const bm = new BattleMetrics('123')
```

I will get the error `TypeError: BattleMetrics is not a constructor`

however if I do the same test in typescript it works fine. In CommonJS I need to use `bm = new BattleMetrics.default()` in order for it to work, but I really would rather avoid that.

If I edit the compiled index.js adding "modules" infront of the .export it works as expected.

How can I resolve this so that when requiring the base file will work both in commonJS and TypeScript

Changed the type of exporting within tsconfig, etc no resolution found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify your main file to export it as a default export like this

```
// main.ts
import BattleMetricsClass from './src/BattleMetrics';

export { BattleMetricsClass as BattleMetrics };
```

This ensures TypeScript to transpile the code, it exports the default export as a named export which becomes compatible with CommonJS

When you import `BattleMetics` you should be able to use it without the `.default()`

```
// test.ts
const { BattleMetrics } = require('../../dist/index.js');

const bm = new BattleMetrics('123');
```